# Linking libraries for Magick++

Tags: c++, compilation

So it's been now 4 hours I've been trying to get Magick++ to work. For some reason, it never occurred me that an external library worked without problems. Usually it takes about six hours of pure time googling.

After a lot of pain I've finally achieved to get the first part of compilation right (extept the tons of warnings), but the linking is problematic. I've found this post about [Imagick linking errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4499218/607407) and this one about [adding the Imagick paths to the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17568161/607407).

After adding the `Imagick/lib` to the *Linker* settings in Visual C++ project this is the only message that coumes out of the compiler:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: stripes, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\lib.obj'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What is this supposed to be? Have I accidentally edited something else?

In `Project properties -> Configuration properties`, I edited following:

- **`VC++ Directories`**

  - **`Include Directories`** - added `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\include`
  - **`Library Directories`** - added `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\lib`
- **`Linker`**

  - **`General`**

    - **`Additional Library Directories`** - added `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\lib`
  - **`Input`**

    - **`Additional Dependencies`**

      - added `CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib`
      - added `CORE_RL_magick__.lib`
      - added `X11_.lib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, even though the library **still** does not work for me, I've overcome this particular problem. It took me another hour.

The solution was to:

1. Download the [source archive here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/windows/ImageMagick-windows.zip).
2. Run the `\VisualMagick\configure\configure.exe`<sup>1</sup>
   [image: ImageMagick configure tool for windows]
3. There should be now a Visual Studio file in `\VisualMagick\VisualDynamicMT.sln`
   [image: Visual magick sln file]
4. Open it. You'll probably need to convert the solution to your visual studio version. Once this is done (it's automatical), clean and build the *`All`* project:
   [image: Building the Magick++ libraries]
5. By this time the libraries and DLLs should be built. You're interested in `\VisualMagick\lib\*`. In the installation folder of imagick, backup all present libraries and then copy (and overwrite) all newly compiled ones.

<sup>**1** All paths are relative to archive root</sup>

The project now compiles [but does not run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27074269/607407).