# My Magick++ project is trying to load wrong DLL

Tags: c++

So it's now 6:30 hours I've been trying to get Magick++ to work. I'm strongly considering writing my own library to save time and nerves.

Currently I'm finally able to compile one of the example files without linker errors, yet my application throws this error:

[image: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)]

> The application was unable to start correctly (`0xc000007b`)

There a [comment suggesting that the application is loading wrong DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10492037/607407#comment13582653_10493137) (32/64 bit), which is very likely, since [it also had messed up the library bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4501402/607407).

The question is: is my assumption right? If it is, what can I do?

Comment: Get Dependency Walker and see what DLL's are dependent on your application.  Then make sure those DLL's are the correct bitness, and they are available to your application.

Comment: How can I *make sure*? I know quite well which ones are being loaded... But what can I do about it? And most importantly, where can I set that bitness in my project?

Comment: Make sure of exactly what?

Comment: "*Make sure those DLL's are the correct bitness.*" Or, preferably, that my application is the correct one.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, there is an `x64` configuration for 64-bit aps, and a `Win32` setting for 32-bit applications.  Also, dependency walker tells you if the app is 32-bit or 64-bit by looking at the "CPU" column information.  You need to get this tool (Dependency Walker).